# Awful Network Performance

Tags: macos, network, performance

I have a MacBook pro running Mountain Lion. When I copy files over the local network, I get around 200Kb/s on a 1Gbps link (the light on the switch indicates 1Gbps). This morning I went to download the XCode 5 DP6 and was pretty apalled by 50Kb/s. Downloading from a Windows 8 machine connected to the same switch yields 2.2Mb/s.

I've tried running the following, but is there anything else I could try?

```
sudo sysctl -w net.inet.tcp.delayed_ack=0
```

Answer (score 1):

Several things:

Do a TCP Dump to analyze traffic, to see if you're machine is hitting sites that are bogging it down. At the command line, type `sudo tcpdump -i en1`

Do a DNS cache reset. At the command line, type `sudo dscacheutil -flushcache`

Check the MTU settings. Confirm with your ISP what the MTU setting should be, and then go to `System Preferences -> Network`. Find your connection and click `Advanced`. Find the `Hardware` tab, and enter the MTU setting manually if it does not match.